# Hub context out side of hub in self hosted signalR application

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

Hello I'm setting up a self hosted hub as explained [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host)

I created my own Hub `class QRCRServiceHub : Hub   {
}`

out side of the Hub, at some other server side  I try this `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<QRCRServiceHub>()`

But I get an exception `"QRCRServiceHub' Hub could not be resolved"`

how can I get the hub context from outside my hub ?

Comment: Are you calling GetHubContext inside the same process you have self-hosting SignalR? If so, is it the call to GetHubContext in the same assembly as the call to WebApp.Start?

Comment: yes, Calling GetHubContext  from same process right after I call WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080");

Comment: Is it an compile time error or a run time exception?

Comment: This is a runtime exception

Comment: Just to verify. Is the QRCRServiceHub also in the same assembly as the call to GetHubContext and the call to WebApp.Start? What happens when you run "signalr ghp /path:myassembly.exe"? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy

Comment: When I run signalr ghp  the server.js file is generated and also there is an warning in the command prompt: "Warning: Could not load file or assembly 'Xceed.Compression.PPMd, Version=3.5.72
73.12150, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba83ff368b7563c6' or one of its depend
encies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is how I managed to solve it, 
The solution was to mark the `class QRCRServiceHub : Hub { }`
as public i.e :  `public class QRCRServiceHub : Hub { }`